# Variations of using .data() in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Would you please tell me, in how many ways jquery's `.data()` can be used.

```
$("element").data('field','value');
```

or

```
$("element").data({'field':'value', 'f2': 'v2' });
```

is there any other way, we can accompany more data like an array or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store any object your like even functions. For an array:

```
$('element').data('field', [ 'elem1', 'elem2' ]);
```

or

```
$('element').data({ someArray: [ 'elem1', 'elem2' ] });
```

Comment: can't we address every element by field names, like in my example

Comment: I am trying to store datas in array and access them like $('element').data('field').('somefield')

Comment: Try this: `$('element').data('field', { someField: 'value1', someOtherField: 'value2' });`. And then to retrieve: `$('element').data('field')['someOtherField']`.

Comment: That's it. Exactly what I wanted

Answer (score 0):

```
var _fn=function TestFunction(){};
var _obj={};
var _arr=[];
jQuery('elm').data('function',_fn);
jQuery('elm').data('object',_obj);
jQuery('elm').data('array',_arr);
```